# Validate unpublished items and give a warning

Tags: sitecore

Scenarion: Content Editor users keeps adding several articles, they can be in different places in the content tree. They want to know that which items has to be published by looking at validations in the content tree.

Can someone help me to write a validation rule to identify whether item is not published and give a warning saying "Item has not been published yet".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's a module called the Published Item Comparer that might do what you need:

http://blog.velir.com/index.php/2011/04/29/published-item-comparer/

Comment: Here is a [Link](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Published_Item_Comparer.aspx) to the Published Item Comparer on the new Sitecore Marketplace

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider using Workflow, and set the final approval step to also publish the item if you want. The user will be able to see what step of the workflow process the items are in the Workbox.